Number of paths with $m$ good pairs of moves
Consider the set $S$ of all paths from $(0, 0)$ to $(n, n)$, formed by sequences of $2n$ moves of the form $(a, b) \rightarrow (a, b + 1)$ or $(a, b) \rightarrow (a + 1, b)$, such that at any point $(x, y)$ in the path, we have $y <= x$. Two consecutive moves that look like $(a, b) \rightarrow (a + 1, b) \rightarrow (a + 1, b + 1)$ are called a good pair of moves. How many paths in $S$ have exactly m good pairs of moves?
Here's what I've done, this may not necessarily be helpful though :
Lets fix these $m$ moves, say at $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), \ldots, (x_m, y_m)$ where these points correspond to the 2nd point (i.e. $(a+1,b)$) of $(a, b) \rightarrow (a + 1, b) \rightarrow (a + 1, b + 1)$.
Once you fix these points the rest of the moves will be uniquely determined, for instance if (1,2) and (3,4) are fixed then you necessarily will need to take the path $(1,2) \rightarrow (1,3) \rightarrow (1,4) \rightarrow (2,4) \rightarrow (3,4)$
We have the following constraints :
$x_1 < x_2 < \ldots < x_m = n$ and $0=y_1 < y_2 < \ldots < y_m$ with $y_{i+1} \leq x_i$
but I cannot really go any further, any help is appreciated

I would count all paths from $(0, 0)$ to $(n, n)$ with $m$ good pairs and subtract from these the paths not in $S$ using the reflection trick

@user1001001 thanks that really simplifies the problem, answer can be easily computed as $\binom{n}{m}^2 - \binom{n+1}{m} \binom{n-1}{m}$.
